# Drupal Best Practice for Settings on Content Type Edit Forms?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I've been curious what is the best practice to add custom settings to the admin/content/types (drupal 6.x)

Update:
Jeremy has suggested (unsurprisingly) to use hook_form_alter(). I'll try it out and report back.

Comment: Read Pro Drupal Development of Vandyk, if i understand you correctly.

Comment: Pro Drupal Developement is indeed an excellent book, but I will not teach you how to ask effective questions. Your question is very short; some more info or examples would make it easier to give you relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

That page is generated by the [node_overview_types()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_overview_types) function, it dosn't look like there is a way to hook into it. Without intercepting the output in the theme layer and messing with it (which I wouldn't advise).

If you want to add content type settings I would suggest you do a [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) on the content type settings form. You can also use hook_node_type_form_alter() to access this form more easily. Have a look [here](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/nodecomment_form_node_type_form/6) for an example.